# Retrieving the next page of items with MSGraph

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a count of the number of items in a Sharepoint List.

I can obtain counts for lists equal to or less than 200. But each page of results contains 200 items and I cannot figure out how to get the next pages.

```
        int listCount = 0;
        Microsoft.Graph.List list = new Microsoft.Graph.List();
        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
        {
            new QueryOption("select", "id"),
            new QueryOption("expand", "columns(select=name),items(expand=fields(select=CustomerName))")
        };
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(scopes).Result;

        list = await graphServiceClient.Sites[$"{siteId}"].Lists[$"{listId}"].Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
        if (list.Items != null)
            {
                listCount = list.Items.Count;
            }
```

I've read through this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging
and this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp

However @odata.nextLink isn't in the response, and converting the pageIterator code from messages to lists doesn't return any data at all.

The items object does have a field called NextPageRequest, but it is null.

Does anyone please have some example code on how to obtain more pages of Sharepoint List items after the first page?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, with some inspiration from
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/891

The answer was to request Lists[{}].Items, which retrieves a ListItemsCollectionPage object which contains a count. If that count is 200, then QueryOptions is used in to repeat the request for the next ItemsPage

```
int listCount = 0;
Microsoft.Graph.IListItemsCollectionPage listItems;  
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(scopes).Result;
listItems = await graphServiceClient.Sites[$"{siteId}"].Lists[$"{listId}"].Items.Request().GetAsync();
itemCount = listItems.Count();
var nextPage = listItems.NextPageRequest;
while (nextPage != null)
{
    listItems = await graphServiceClient.Sites[$"{siteId}"].Lists[$"{listId}"].Items.Request(nextPage.QueryOptions).GetAsync();
    itemCount = itemCount + listItems.Count();
    nextPage = listItems.NextPageRequest;
}
```